# how to refresh data in cache on state reload- angular 1.5 / ui-router

Tags: angularjs, caching

I am working on a task where I have a bunch of widgets on a dashboard.  When the user changes the customer on the dashboard the `$state` is reloaded, and the widgets' position should be saved to a cache, but the data relevant to the widgets should be refreshed. There are two relevant components, a header component where the customer is changed, and the dashboard component where the widgets are. I'd like to accomplish this without touching the header component.

Previously, I wrote a function to remove all data related properties from the cache after saving in the cache, but I think that might not be the right approach and too complicated. what is the best way to accomplish this?

so suppose each widget looks like this:

```
 {
 widgetType: chart, 
 position: someCoordinatesThatStayTheSameOnStateChange,
 chart: containsDataThatNeedsToBeRefreshed,
 chartData: containsDataThatNeedsToBeRefreshed
}
```

this is a `$resolve`'d function in my routes file which exposes `$ctrl.widgets` in the dashboard controller:

```
widgets($http, $q, CacheFactory, WidgetsService) {
      'ngInject';
      let mockWidgetData = WidgetsService.getAllWidgets();
      let widgetsCache = CacheFactory.get('widgets');
      if (!widgetsCache) {
        CacheFactory.createCache('widgets', {
          storageMode: 'localStorage',
        });
      }
      return mockWidgetData;
    },
```

relevant places where I save data in a cache in the dashboard controller:

```
let widgetsCache = CacheFactory.get('widgets');
  let widgetsCacheItems = widgetsCache.get('widgets');

  gridsterConfig.resizable.stop = function(event, $element, widget) {
    widgetsCache.put("widgets", $ctrl.widgets);
   //clearDataFromCache()
  }
  gridsterConfig.draggable.stop = function(event, $element, widget) {
    widgetsCache.put("widgets", $ctrl.widgets);
    //clearDataFromCache()
  }
  $ctrl.toggleVisibility = function(widget) {
    widget.hidden = !widget.hidden;
    widgetsCache.put("widgets", $ctrl.widgets);
   //clearDataFromCache()
  }
```

old function I wrote:

```
function clearDataFromCache() {
        let widgetObjectsInCache = widgetsCache.get('widgets');
        widgetObjectsInCache.forEach((widget) => {
          if (widget.chart) delete widget.chart;
          if (widget.chartConfig) delete widget.chartConfig;
        })
        console.log(widgetObjectsInCache, "THE CACHE AFTER REMOVING ANY DATA RELATED STUFF");
      }
```

Comment: Do you really want to delete data on $state reload (I am assuming that its refresh of same state) or do you want to refetch data?

Comment: I think re-fetching data makes more sense, but the only data that needs to be refetched is for the charts

Comment: You can use resolve function for state to refetch the data you want. Please check https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c#.3qi1jjy7d

Comment: thanks that worked! I added a resolve function for the "liveData" that I wanted and on init, I overwrite the relevant widgets with the liveData

Comment: you can add your comment as an answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use resolve function for state to refetch the data you want. Please check https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c?swoff=true#.bkudisx52